# Strange behavior of WebReponse.GetStream

Tags: c#, .net, stream, download, httpwebresponse

I'm writing web downloader and have met the strange problem. 
  Sample code:

```
 int chunk;
 var request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;

  using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
  {
      using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
      {
           using (Stream file = File.Create(filePath))
           {
               long byteReaded = 0;
               long contentLength = response.ContentLength;
               while (byteReaded < contentLength)
               {
                    long bytesCountToRead = contentLength - byteReaded > chunk ? chunk : contentLength - byteReaded;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesCountToRead];
                    responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    file.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    byteReaded += bytesCountToRead;
                }
            }
      }
  }
```

**PROBLEM** :
 When 'chunk' variable == 1 or 2 bytes it's ok. But when this size is larger - images become disturbed! I've figured out that it is something with download speed(response reading speed), because when i set larger size of `chunk` and insert `Thread.Sleep(time)` at the last line of `while` cycle, images stay normal.
 Wish someone could help me.

[image: 1 byte chunk size]
[image: 50 Kbytes chunk size]

Comment: Maybe it's not important, but put some parens around you `long bytesCountToRead = ...`. I am sure, it is not what you want it to be!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not strange at all - you're just misusing streams. You're *assuming* that a single call to `Read` will read the whole of the buffer you've asked for. That's not the case - it can easily return less. You should change this:

```
responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
file.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
byteReaded += bytesCountToRead;
```

to:

```
int chunkRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
file.Write(buffer, 0, chunkRead);
byteReaded += chunkRead;
```

You should *never* ignore the return value of `Stream.Read`.

Additionally, there's no need to create a *new* byte array on each iteration.

Finally, if you're using .NET 4, all of this can be written *much* more simply:

```
using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    using (Stream file = File.Create(filePath))
    {
        responseStream.CopyTo(file);
    }
}
```

(Or just use `WebClient` / `HttpClient` to start with...)

Comment: You are my savior! Thank you

Comment: I've started with WebClient, but it's harder to stop it, and to pause with saving progress.